# One/Either of the books is a must-read. - Differences between "either of" and "one of"?

Tags: usage

There are two books.
What are the differences between Example 1 and Example 2?

**Example 1**

> One of the books is a must-read.

**Example 2**

> Either of the books is a must-read.

Comment: Both utterances are "weird". It's highly unlikely only ***one*** of the books is a must-read, so probably the intended meaning should be expressed as ***Both** of the books are a must-read* (or ***...are must-reads*** - the preferred syntax for "casual coinages" such as the noun ***must-read*** isn't exactly set in stone).

Comment: It's okay to say ***Either** book is **worth reading***, because the implication is the addressee might not have the time or inclination to read both (so he can pick either of them). But it makes no sense to say ***Either** book is a **must-read***, because the attribute ***must-read*** doesn't leave scope for addressee to only read one book - he ***must read both books***.

Answer (score 3):

**One book** is a "must-read" in example 1.

**Two books** are a "must-read" in example 2.

Example 1 implies that only one out of the total number of books is a "must-read".

In Example 2, both books are considered a "must-read". You could choose either of the two books and would always end up with a "must-read".

Comment: If both books are a must-read, then you need to read both books. As soon as there is an alternative book for you to read instead of the first one, then the first one ceases to be a must-read.

Answer (score 0):

For example 1: one of the books is boring/unsuitable/irrelevant but the statement does not distinguish which book is the "must read" and which is the other.

For example 2: both books are "must reads", but reading just one of them is sufficient. The statement does not guide as to which is best, leaving the choice to the reader.

Comment: If reading either one of the two books is sufficient then neither of the books is a must-read.

Comment: ... and the fact that a book is not a must-read doesn't necessarily imply that it's "boring, unsuitable or irrelevant."  It may simply supply fascinating and highly relevant - though non-essential - information.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that if you say "one of the books is a must-read," then what you mean is quite literally that one of them is a must-read, almost certainly with the implication that the other isn't.

However, I don't think the second example is a good solution either. Its meaning is at best inelegantly expressed (if not entirely self-contradictory). In fact, the only way I can squeeze a modicum of sense out of the sentence is by concluding that *neither of the books is a must-read*, since it appears you need not read one of them as long as you read the other.

I'd express that intention very differently (dispensing with the expression "must-read" altogether):

e.g.: "You'll need to read one or other [of the two books]."

Comment: No. It's "...almost certainly with the implication that the other **is also a must-read**". Otherwise we'd have to suppose the context is some kind of weird "guessing game" where the addressee is being invited to figure out which book is essential reading, and which isn't. And *that* would probably require the addressee to read both books so he could tell which was which.